# Anyone can explain why the number of bins in the histogram are lower when collecting features?

Tags: python, computer-vision, histogram

I am developing an algorithm to extract the LBP histogram of an image. I use a demofile.txt with some annotations of my image classification characteristics.

The demofile.txt have annotations of each image divided in 3 ROI:

**image1 33 33 100**

**image2 66 100 33**

...

**image1000 66 66 66**

For example, image1, in the first ROI the classification is class 33, the second ROI is class 33 and the third class 100.

To extract the LBP histogram I use this piece of code. I save the features extracted in the features_lbp.txt

```
#calculate and returns the lbp histogram with "lbp_params" of the image "img"
def lbp_feature_correct(img, lbp_params):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ## Get the LBP Histogram
    lbp = feature.local_binary_pattern( gray, lbp_params["points"], lbp_params["radius"], lbp_params["method"] )
    n_bins = int(lbp.max() + 1)
    (hist, bins) = np.histogram(lbp.ravel(), density=True, bins=n_bins, range=(0, n_bins))
    return hist, lbp

## LBP parameters ##
lbp_params = dict(points=8,
    radius=2,
    method="nri_uniform")

f = open("features_lbp.txt", "w")
count_line = 0

f_dataset = open("demofile.txt", "r")
line = f_dataset.readline()

while(line != ''):
    array = line.split(' ')
    imageName = array[0]
    print("Nome da imagem: " + imageName)
    img = cv2.imread("../images/output/" + imageName + ".jpg")
    
    #resize
    imgResized = cv2.resize(img, (640,480))
    
    cv2.imwrite("Dataset/"+ imageName + ".jpg", imgResized)
    #get 3 rectangles from the image
    #cv2.rectangle(imgResized, (227,10), (414, 150), (0,0,255), 2)
    rectangle1 = imgResized[10:150, 227:414]
    rectangle2 = imgResized[160:300, 227:414]
    rectangle3 = imgResized[310:450, 227:414]
    
    final_hist = calculate_final_histogram(rectangle1)
    #save the final histogram
    np.savetxt(f, final_hist, newline=' ')
    f.write("\n")
    count_line+=1
    
    final_hist = calculate_final_histogram(rectangle2)
    #save the final histogram
    np.savetxt(f, final_hist, newline=' ')
    f.write("\n")
    count_line+=1

    final_hist = calculate_final_histogram(rectangle3)
    #save the final histogram
    np.savetxt(f, final_hist, newline=' ')
    f.write("\n")
    count_line+=1

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    line = f_dataset.readline()

print("Linhas guardadas "+ str(count_line))

#return and calculate the final histogram (junction of lbp histogram and another histogram based on an index(RGVVI, GLI, VARI, NGRDI))
def calculate_final_histogram(img):
    
    #calculate lbp histogram
    lbp_hist , _ = lbp_feature_correct(img, lbp_params)
    #lbp_hist = []
    
    #calculate RGBVI histogram
    #index_hist = calculate_vegetaion_index(img, "rgbvi")
    index_hist = []
    
    #calculate Hue (HSV) histogram
    #hue_hist = calculate_hue_histogram(img)
    hue_hist = []

    #join the histograms
    final_hist = np.concatenate((lbp_hist, index_hist, hue_hist),axis=None)
    print(len(final_hist))
    return final_hist
```

This works for almost every image of the dataset, but sometimes, instead of extracting 59 bins it only extracts 58 and I dont know why this happens. To reproduce the example it is necessary a dataset of images and the demofile.txt. The images name and the demofile.txt items must be the same. For example if the first image of the dataset is image1 in the demofile.txt it must be image1 30 30 66.

Comment: What is `calculate_final_histogram()`? Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: Hello, the `calculate_final_histogram()` is the concatenation of LBP histogram with other histogram. But in this case it is returning only the LBP.

Comment: I guess, instead of `n_bins = int(lbp.max() + 1)` use a static number of bins. You know how many different values the LBP can produce depending on which options you give it, there is no need to guess by looking at the max value returned. What if not all values are produced? This is the issue you’re seeing.